# "Hello, World!!" in .NET 4 generates 3500 page faults

Tags: c#, .net

I'm running Windows Vista and Visual Studio 2010, using .NET 4.
2 GB of RAM and about 800 MB free.

I create a Windows Form application and add no code to it. Just compile it in release mode, close Visual Studio and start the application. If I look in task manager the application generated 3500 page faults for just starting and doing nothing.

If I create a console application and just add a `Console.ReadLine();` to keep it open it generates 1500 page faults.

Is that normal behaviour for .NET? These numbers seem ridiculously high to me.

Comment: Can you post the text of one of the page faults ?

Comment: Is this only for your app, or any .Net app? And what if you use a different runtime?

Comment: @Alan B - This is an operating system page fault, where the system swaps a section of memory between RAM and the hard drive. The number of these that the application makes is a metric you can monitor in the windows process viewer.

Comment: They don't seem that surprising to me. Given that page faults are the mechanism by which anything gets loaded, and just about any application ends up loading a large number of dependent DLLs, etc.

Comment: I'd guess that is just the CLR being loaded? Maybe JIT compilation?

Comment: 3500 * 4 kilobytes (assuming x86) is only 13.7 megabytes

Comment: Ever since my first OS theory course at university, I've always thought the phrase "page *fault*" was an overly-alarming description for what is actually happening.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have to understand that there's more code to a .NET application than just the code you wrote. It has to load the assembly, parse it, compile it, execute it, then load in various support libraries, etc.. (some of which may require similar parsing, compiling, etc..), and all of those things create page faults. 3,500 is not that many page faults in the grand scheme of things.

As an example, I tried out a few "simple" console applications. More, run from a console, generates 750 page faults, and this is a pretty tiny application that does little more than echo from one input to the other.  It's written in C, a language that is not garbage collected, doesn't have a virtual machine, or a big runtime library that has to come with it (it's statically linked, so it's not depending on a runtime).

Given all that .NET does, a single line console application that just does a ReadLine using only 1,500 page faults seems quite good.

I'm not even sure why you care about page faults. Perhaps you are coming from a platform where page faults are a bad thing. In Windows, processes are "page backed", which means that the OS memory maps an executable, and then demand loads pages as needed (this includes shared libraries, as well as the executable itself, icons, images, all kinds of things). Each of those pages generate a page fault when the OS needs to load them into memory. That's normal, and that's the way the OS works.

Comment: Every page (each 4kB) of the Windows and .NET dll's loaded will be a single page fault. So 3500 is not very much.

Comment: @Richard 4kB * 3500 page faults = 13.671875 mB, while in modern computing that really isn't much, it's not insignificant.

Comment: @TheLukeMcCarthy s/mB/MB/ I think (what's a millibyte?). And much of that should have been satisfied from cache. The problem is for a hello world the one off overhead dominates. Better to look at a substantive application's sustained hard page fault rate. I wonder what the count would be for a C app not using the CRT (ie. call `WriteConsole` directly).

Comment: @Richard a millibyte is 1024 killibytes :-P lol I agree that the overhead for "Hello World" is quite large, as @GvS said in his answer .Net was designed for business development. I'm Not sure what the memory usage would be for a C app, it would depend on the compiler and libraries I suspect.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think one of the targets of .NET was to create a "Hello, World!" application with minimal resources. .NET does a lot of work on startup to go beyond "Hello, World!" applications and run business application, making a tradeoff between usage of resources and development time.

Conclusion: It is normal to that .NET uses a lot for resources (memory, page faults, etc.) on small applications. Things normalize when creating "normal" applications, but it will still consume more resources than simple C or assembler.