# Is it possible to determine the source of a Soft Page Fault in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I am observing the occasional soft page fault in my .NET app. This is surprising, as I have designed it not to generate page faults in the steady state.

Out of interest, is it possible to check what part of the my program (or .NET framework) is generating these soft page faults as they occur?

Is it possible to work out which heap or stack the soft page fault is being generated on, i.e. stack for thread1, 2, 3, or heap for gen0, gen1, gen2, large object, etc?

**Update**

Decided not to bother with soft page faults. For 99.9% of normal applications, this does not impact performance at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Do you really need to bother about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014892/hello-world-in-net-4-generates-3500-page-faults)?

If the page faults are blocking execution you should be able to profile the app to find the parts that are taking the longest to execute.  If they are not blocking execution then good for you...

Comment: Yes, because there is a slight issue with the .NET framework: when using BeginReceiveAsync on a socket, any page faults delay the incoming UDP packets by hundreds of microseconds (something to do with locking in a driver preventing page faults from occurring, which blocks all other threads from executing). This mounts up, hitting the application throughput badly. We can see this effect in the VS2012 profiler, and want to know what part of the program (or .NET framework) is generating the page faults.